# how to push objective c view controller to swift view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

in my objective-c view controller i need push to next swift view controller, my basic project - obj c, after add swift file, Xcode generate Bridging-Header.h, but i not see -swift.h file

hot to push in swift View from obj-c view ?

```
-(void)longTapInDaClub:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longTap {

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mail" bundle:nil];
nextView *view = (nextView *) [stb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"next"];
[nextView getIdSample: _idSample];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

nextView - is Swift view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved problem - in project settings -> build settings -> product module name -> and enter valid name with no special chars and digital char - rebuild project and #import "moduleName-swift.h"

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same - you are using the storyboard to define the transitions and your push to segue will be connected up to the swift view controller. So as long as the 'next' is pointing to the right place it doesn't matter if it's swift or not.

Comment: no, i need long press button action  and use getter in swift view :(

Comment: run it in a debugger and find out whether your nextView is nil or not, and if so, check you have a named segue from your current one to the next one.

Comment: sorry, i not understand - how to seque with long press ?))